# Boost buffer_cast cannot convert from void* to PointerToPodType

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am interested in Socket communication and use boost library. When i got a message from server and try to convert it `atomic<uint8_t>*` it gaves me an error that  `'static_cast': cannot convert from 'const void*' to 'PointerToPodType'`. I could not understand why it gaves me that error.

Code sample

```
atomic<uint8_t>* buffer = new atomic<uint8_t>[10000];

boost::asio::streambuf receive_buffer;
boost::asio::read(*sock, receive_buffer, boost::asio::transfer_all(), this->ec);
    if (this->ec && this->ec != boost::asio::error::eof) {

        cout << "receive failed:" << this->ec.message() << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        ///ERROR IS HERE
        buffer = boost::asio::buffer_cast< atomic<uint8_t>*>(receive_buffer.data());

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not C, don't use `new`, `malloc` (or `delete` or `free`).

Specically, I see pointers to sockets, pointers to everything. You leak the entire buffer allocated with `new` if you made the assignment work.

Here's a simpler take, cutting the double-buffering (`streambuf` adds little):

```
uint8_t buffer[10000];

auto transferred = boost::asio::read(
        sock,
        boost::asio::buffer(buffer),
        boost::asio::transfer_all(),
        ec);
```

Now on success, `tranferred` bytes will be inside your allocated buffer already. Even simpler with a

```
std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(10000);
```

Because then you can simply

```
buffer.resize(transferred);
```

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63d718cfd80991d9)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::asio::ip::address_v4;

int main() {
    //uint8_t buffer[10000];
    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(10000);

    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    tcp::socket sock(ioc);
    sock.connect({address_v4::from_string("173.203.57.63"), 80});
    write(sock, boost::asio::buffer("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: coliru.stacked-crooked.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"));

    boost::system::error_code ec;
    auto transferred = boost::asio::read(
            sock,
            boost::asio::buffer(buffer),
            boost::asio::transfer_all(),
            ec);

    if (ec && ec != boost::asio::error::eof) {
        std::cout << "receive failed:" << ec.message() << std::endl;
    } else {
        buffer.resize(transferred);
        std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << std::setfill('0');
        int n = 0;
        for (int i : buffer) {
            std::cout
                << std::setw(4) << i
                << " '" << char(std::isgraph(i)?i : '.') << "'"
                << (++n % 8? ' ':'\n');
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
0x48 'H' 0x54 'T' 0x54 'T' 0x50 'P' 0x2f '/' 0x31 '1' 0x2e '.' 0x31 '1'
0x20 '.' 0x32 '2' 0x30 '0' 0x30 '0' 0x20 '.' 0x4f 'O' 0x4b 'K' 0x20 '.'
00xd '.' 00xa '.' 0x43 'C' 0x6f 'o' 0x6e 'n' 0x74 't' 0x65 'e' 0x6e 'n'
0x74 't' 0x2d '-' 0x54 'T' 0x79 'y' 0x70 'p' 0x65 'e' 0x3a ':' 0x20 '.'
0x74 't' 0x65 'e' 0x78 'x' 0x74 't' 0x2f '/' 0x68 'h' 0x74 't' 0x6d 'm'
 ... 1100 lines snipped
0x20 '.' 0x20 '.' 0x7d '}' 0x3b ';' 00xa '.' 0x3c '<' 0x2f '/' 0x73 's'
0x63 'c' 0x72 'r' 0x69 'i' 0x70 'p' 0x74 't' 0x3e '>' 00xa '.' 0x3c '<'
0x2f '/' 0x68 'h' 0x74 't' 0x6d 'm' 0x6c 'l' 0x3e '>' 00xa '.'
```

### Dynamic/Heap allocation

`std::vector` already does heap allocation. I you insist on the raw C array semantics, consider [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/371f65c8c8996b3f):

```
 auto buffer = std::make_unique<std::array<std::atomic<uint8_t, 10'000> > >();
 // ...
        boost::asio::buffer(*buffer),
 // ...
    size_t n = 0;
    for (int i : *buffer) {
        if (n>=transferred) break;
        std::cout
            << std::setw(4) << i
            << " '" << char(std::isgraph(i)?i : '.') << "'"
            << (++n % 8? ' ':'\n');
    }
```

Or even [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89868cf9d3d48c2f):

```
auto buffer = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(10'000);
// ...
        boost::asio::buffer(buffer.get(), 10'000),
// ...
    size_t n = 0;
    for (auto it = buffer.get(); it <= buffer.get() + transferred; ++it) {
        std::cout
            << std::setw(4) << static_cast<int>(*it)
            << " '" << char(std::isgraph(*it)?*it : '.') << "'"
            << (++n % 8? ' ':'\n');
    }
```

As you can see the operation with "manual" buffers like this is much more error-prone, but at least now you donot have a memory leak.

Comment: Compiler does not give an error but when i read ,program is hanging on read function.If i change read to async_read it works but i dont want to change it with async_read.

Comment: That means there is never a close? You're specifically waiting for the other end to "hang up" (`transfer_all`). Try with `transfer_exactly(somesmallnumber)` or just use a small buffer. In that case the call will also return when the buffer is full or the requested number of bytes have been transferred. Of course, if the other end never sends a response... you'll still wait. (That's why I used an HTTP request to "force" a response, and used the "Connection: close" header)

Comment: do read function get every byte while open ? omg i thought that read function is like recv function from winsock2.h

Comment: `transfer_all` kind of says it all :) You even checked for the expected `eof` condition... [`socket.read_some`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/read_some.html) is more like that, but then again, that's stepping down to C-land again. Why would you? Realistically you want to transmit a certain protocol. So, consider [`boost::asio::read_until`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until.html)  to match your protocol's framing.